# VsCode for Java backend development?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, backend

I'm using VSCode for java. If I want to be a java developer, can I use VsCode for future coding or I should change it (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans)?

Comment: if you can compile your code in a way you find easy: use it until you find a simpler way. If the editor supplies you with the features you want or can expand the editor stick with it.

Comment: Switching one platform to another is easy. What's important is the learning of coding language, so it's not necessary for you to doubt if vscode is worth for future coding. Compared to IDE, VS Code is more friendly for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode support is improving for java, but it is not good as Eclipse yet. If you are looking for free software, then I recommend Eclipse. Paid version of Intellij is really good.

One suggestion is to learn your IDE well.  Learn common tasks and use of debugger well.